Can image 2 be obtained by rotating image 1 by 72 degrees each time
    \documentclass[border=0cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}   
\coordinate(o)at(1.5,1.5);
      \coordinate(a)at(1.5,2.5);
      \coordinate(a1)at(1.3,2.2);
      \coordinate(a2)at(1.7,2.2);        
        \draw[fill=black] plot[smooth] coordinates {(o) (a1) (a)} -- plot[smooth] coordinates { (a) (a2) (o)} --cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document} 




best would be to save it in a box, say, so you only plot it once.

You can just do it using \foreach. Note however that you can't rotate coordinates if you set them outside the \foreach block. For that reason the following doesn't use coordinates but the points directly. Also I moved everything by (-1.5,-1.5).
\documentclass[border=0cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}   
  \foreach\x in{0,72,...,288}
    \draw[fill=black,rotate=\x]
      plot[smooth] coordinates {(0,0) (-.2,.7) (0,1)}
      -- plot[smooth] coordinates { (0,1) (.2,.7) (0,0)}
      -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


(yay, screenshot with cursor)

thank you very much,.

Can you tell me why using my coordinates cannot achieve this effect.

Because coordinates have a fixed place and aren't affected by rotate (unless you set the coordinates inside the rotated code as shown in the other answer).

Why 298 and not 288?

@nneonneo :D Because I was somehow distracted enough to miscalculate that :):):)

another solution with foreach with a rotation around any point (o) (not only the origin) using scope and the {calc} library for calculations.
I wrote the coordinates of points (a), (a1) and (a2) in a local coordinate system (the center of the rotation).
    \documentclass[border=0cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}   
\draw (0,0) -- (0,3);
\draw (0,0) -- (3,0);
\coordinate(o)at(1.5,1.5);

\foreach \aa in{0,1,2,3,4}{
\begin{scope}[shift={(o)},rotate={\aa*72}]
      \coordinate(a)at(0,1);
      \coordinate(a1)at(-0.2,0.7);
      \coordinate(a2)at(0.2,0.7); 
\draw[red,fill=red] plot[smooth]coordinates {(0,0) (a1) (a)} -- plot[smooth] coordinates { (a) (a2) (0,0)} --cycle;
\end{scope}
}

\coordinate(o2) at (2,-1);

\foreach \aa in{0,1,2,3,4}{
\begin{scope}[shift={(o2)},rotate={\aa*72}]
      \coordinate(a)at(0,1);
      \coordinate(a1)at(-0.2,0.7);
      \coordinate(a2)at(0.2,0.7); 
\draw[blue,fill=blue] plot[smooth]coordinates {(0,0) (a1) (a)} -- plot[smooth] coordinates { (a) (a2) (0,0)} --cycle;
\end{scope}
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document} 


